# Strange linker (ld) behavior, it sees only half of class's methods

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, ld

I have 2 targets in XCode, an executable containing class Record like

```
class Record
{
  public:
  const char * getFirstName() const;
  void setFirsttName(const char * firstName);

  const char * getCompany() const;
  void setCompany(const char * company);
  ...
 }
```

And a unit test bundle, which is linked to executable via bundleLoader and contains test like

```
...
Record record;
record.setFirsttName("aaa");
record.setCompany("bbb");
```

The strange and annoying thing is, I get a linker error saying that it doesnt see setCompany symbol, but it sees setFirsttName. Complete cleans and rebuilds dont help the matter. Can anyone help?

#### Edit 1:

It was DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING = YES. Aaargh!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a definition of `setCompany` in your source file for `Record`?  What is in the header is just a declaration, and you need a definition to link programs that use the method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to define `setCompany` in your source file? Alternately did you forget to qualify it with the `ClassName::` so it's treated as a class method?